# Django - redirect to home after login when session times out

Tags: django, django-authentication

If I'm on foo.html (any view/template) and the session times out, and then I click on a link to bar.html (any other view), I'm taken to the login page. After successful authentication, I am redirected to bar.html. I want it to always redirect to home.html. My settings.py has `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'`.

Users are prompted to login after the sessions expires because all my views require the user to be logged in.  In CBV I use:

```
@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class QuestionListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
```

In functional views I have a decorator:

```
@ login_required
def home(request):
```

I am using the django auth and have not overridden the login view. My login.html file contains:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 pl-4">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Looking at the django code, I think the answer lies in django.contrib.auth.views:

```
class RedirectURLMixin:
    next_page = None
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    success_url_allowed_hosts = set()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.get_redirect_url() or self.get_default_redirect_url()

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        """Return the user-originating redirect URL if it's safe."""
        redirect_to = self.request.POST.get(
        self.redirect_field_name, self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name)
    )
        url_is_safe = url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(
            url=redirect_to,
            allowed_hosts=self.get_success_url_allowed_hosts(),
            require_https=self.request.is_secure(),
    )
        return redirect_to if url_is_safe else ""

    def get_success_url_allowed_hosts(self):
        return {self.request.get_host(), *self.success_url_allowed_hosts}

    def get_default_redirect_url(self):
        """Return the default redirect URL."""
        if self.next_page:
            return resolve_url(self.next_page)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("No URL to redirect to. Provide a next_page.")
```

My guess is that `def get_default_redirect` is happening because I click on a link (the next_page) which triggers the login (because of the session time out).

The only reason I want to have all logins go to the home page is because I'm temporarily putting an announcement banner on the home page. It's possible for a user to not see the banner if they never go to the home page by simply logging in using the method described here.

Comment: Can you share your view? And also can you please clarify that you want it to always redirect to home.html, after logged in and also logged out?

Comment: This happens with all my views, even with the simplest CBV such as ListView. I believe it is the default behaviour of django. I'm only interested in the redirect after logged in.